# Is flattening arrays by mem::transmute safe?

Tags: rust

Is flattening an array like this safe for build in primitive types?

```
let a = [[0u32;4];4];
let b = std::mem::transmute::<[[u32;4];4], [u32; 16]>(a);
```

What are the conditions under this this is safe?

Comment: A similar operation is available (unstably) in the standard library: [`<[T]>::flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.flatten). I believe the only reason this operation isn't available in the standard library is that it requires `generic_const_exprs`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays are one of the few data structures with guaranteed memory layouts in Rust. The array `[T; N]` is guaranteed to be laid out as `N` consecutive instances of `T` in memory. Thus `[[T; M]; N]` is guaranteed to have the same memory layout as `[T; M * N]`, and transmuting from one to the other is safe for any type `T`.

Comment: Could there be a problem with over alignment on [T;N]?

Comment: @Unlikus No. [An array has the same alignment as the element type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#array-layout).